# C# service with async thread massive unknown UC use

Tags: c#, multithreading, service, task

I'm currently working on an application that should take CAO files and convert them to other format.

I have a web application that allow user to deposit file and to get converted ones.

I have a service that run every 15 seconds, look for a file to be converted, start a thread with conversion process. It stores working task and check at each turn if one is finished.

My service works, it converts file exactly as I want. However, when I start the conversion manually my UC is half used than when I use the service. Which mean I've probably done something that I shouldn't have done. Probably a stupid mistake or misunderstanding of something.

The point is that I don't find any clue on what can make my CPU go this high because of the service.

Can someone explain me where is the problem ?

Main class:(This is a test main, for the debug purpose)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
      Worker.run();
      Thread.Sleep(15000);
}
Worker.WaitAll();
```

Worker.run() :

```
public static List<Task<RETURN_VALUE>> m_tasks = new List<Task<RETURN_VALUE>>();
    public static Dictionary<Int32, CancellationTokenSource> m_cancellationTokenSources = new Dictionary<int, CancellationTokenSource>();

    public static void run()
    {
        //Clean
        ServiceCleaner.CleanUploads();
        ServiceCleaner.CleanDownloads();
        SpaceManager.MaxSizeReached();
        #region thread watching
        if (m_tasks.Count > 0)
        {
            #region thread must be cancel

            //Cancel thread
            List<Task<RETURN_VALUE>> _removeTemp = new List<Task<RETURN_VALUE>>();
            foreach (Task<RETURN_VALUE> _task in m_tasks)
            {
                if (DbWorker.mustBeCancel((Int32)_task.AsyncState))
                {
                    m_cancellationTokenSources[(Int32)_task.AsyncState].Cancel();
                    //Cancellation actions
                    DbWorker.CancelRequest((Int32)_task.AsyncState);
                    ServiceCleaner.CleanCanceledRequest((Int32)_task.AsyncState);
                    //task must be remove
                    _removeTemp.Add(_task);
                }
            }
            foreach (Task<RETURN_VALUE> _taskToRemove in _removeTemp)
            {
                m_tasks.Remove(_taskToRemove);
            }

            #endregion thread must be cancel

            #region AnyEnd
            List<Task<RETURN_VALUE>> _removeTemp2 = new List<Task<RETURN_VALUE>>();
            foreach (Task<RETURN_VALUE> _task in m_tasks)
            {
                if (_task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                {
                    RETURN_VALUE _taskResult = _task.Result;
                    Int32 _taskID = (Int32)_task.AsyncState;
                    switch (_taskResult)
                    {
                        case RETURN_VALUE.CONVERTED:
                            DbWorker.setToConverted(_taskID);
                            break;

                        case RETURN_VALUE.LICENCE:
                            DbWorker.setToHighPriority(_taskID);
                            break;

                        case RETURN_VALUE.ERROR:
                            DbWorker.setToError(_taskID);
                            break;

                        case RETURN_VALUE.INCORRECT:
                            DbWorker.setToIncorrect(_taskID);
                            break;
                    }
                    m_cancellationTokenSources.Remove(_taskID);
                    _removeTemp2.Add(_task);
                }
            }
            foreach (Task<RETURN_VALUE> _taskToRemove in _removeTemp2)
            {
                m_tasks.Remove(_taskToRemove);
            }

            #endregion AnyEnd
        }

        #endregion thread watching
        if (m_tasks.Count < ServiceConfig.LICENCE_QTY)
        {
            Tuple<Task<RETURN_VALUE>, Int32, CancellationTokenSource> _result = Converter.StartTask(m_cancellationTokenSources);
            if (_result != null)
            {
                m_tasks.Add(_result.Item1);
                m_cancellationTokenSources.Add(_result.Item2, _result.Item3);
            }
        }
    }
```

Note : DbWorker is a simple class that just contain static method that will get/set datas in the sql server db. ServiceCleaner is the part that go in folders and just wipe directories, I'll put them if someone think it can be the problem.

StartTask():

```
    public static Tuple<Task<RETURN_VALUE>, Int32, CancellationTokenSource> StartTask(Dictionary<Int32, CancellationTokenSource> m_cancelationSources)
    {
        Task<RETURN_VALUE> _task = null;
        // Get conversion if any
        Int32 _requestNeeded = DbWorker.getRequestToDo();
        if (_requestNeeded != 0 && !m_cancelationSources.ContainsKey(_requestNeeded))
        {
            DbWorker.setToProcessing(_requestNeeded);
            ServiceCleaner.CleanBeforeConvert(_requestNeeded);
            // Create task
            CancellationTokenSource _srcCancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
            try
            {
                //_task = Task.Factory.StartNew(_testId => Converter.testRunner<Int32>((Int32)_testId, _srcCancel.Token), _requestNeeded, _srcCancel.Token);
                _task = Task.Factory.StartNew(_testId => Converter.ConverterRunner<Int32>((Int32)_testId, _srcCancel.Token), _requestNeeded, _srcCancel.Token);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            //Edit request
            return Tuple.Create(_task, _requestNeeded, _srcCancel);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And lastly, ConverterRunner :

```
public static RETURN_VALUE ConverterRunner<T>(T _id, CancellationToken token)
    {
        Runspace _runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        _runSpace.Open();
        // Récupération des fichiers d'entrées
        List<String> _inputFiles = FileGiver.getFilesToConvert(Convert.ToInt32(_id));
        Int32 i = 0;
        // Boucle sur l'ensemble des fichiers d'entrée
        while (i < _inputFiles.Count)
        {
            String _inputFile = _inputFiles[i];
            // Cancel ?
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                return RETURN_VALUE.CANCELED;
            }
            // Command creation
            String _outputPath = String.Empty;
            String _outputLog = String.Empty;
            // Dans le cas d'un zip
            if (_inputFile.Substring(ServiceConfig.INPUT_ZIP_FOLDER.Length) == ServiceConfig.INPUT_ZIP_FOLDER)
            {
                _outputPath = ServiceConfig.OUTPUT_FOLDER + _inputFile.Substring(ServiceConfig.INPUT_ZIP_FOLDER.Length);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(_outputPath));
                _outputLog = ServiceConfig.OUTPUT_LOG_FOLDER + _inputFile.Substring(ServiceConfig.INPUT_ZIP_FOLDER.Length);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(_outputLog));
                _outputLog = Path.ChangeExtension(_outputLog, "log");
            }
            // Fichier seul
            else
            {
                _outputPath = ServiceConfig.OUTPUT_FOLDER + _inputFile.Substring(ServiceConfig.INPUT_FOLDER.Length);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(_outputPath));
                _outputLog = ServiceConfig.OUTPUT_LOG_FOLDER + _inputFile.Substring(ServiceConfig.INPUT_FOLDER.Length);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(_outputLog));
                _outputLog = Path.ChangeExtension(_outputLog, "log");
            }

            String _command = ServiceConfig.BATCAVE;
            _command += " ";
            _command += "-batch";
            _command += " ";
            _command += ServiceConfig.SCRIPT_PATH;
            _command += " ";
            _command += _inputFile;
            _command += " ";
            _command += "Acrobat";
            _command += " ";
            _command += "pdf";
            _command += " ";
            _command += _outputPath;
            _command += " ";
            _command += _outputLog;
            // Lancement d'une conversion
            Pipeline _pipePwShell = _runSpace.CreatePipeline(_command);
            _pipePwShell.Input.Close();
            _pipePwShell.InvokeAsync();
            Boolean _end = false;
            // Boucle d'attente d'un résultat
            while (!_end)
            {
                // Cancel ?
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    _pipePwShell.StopAsync();
                    return RETURN_VALUE.CANCELED;
                }
                if (_pipePwShell.Output.Count > 0)
                {
                    _end = true;
                    Int32 _returnCode = Convert.ToInt32(_pipePwShell.Output.Read().ToString());
                    // if not started-> exit with licence problem
                    if (_returnCode == (Int32)RETURN_CODE.OUT_OF_LICENCE)
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            return RETURN_VALUE.LICENCE;
                        }
                    }
                    // Converted ?
                    if (_returnCode == (Int32)RETURN_CODE.CONVERTED)
                    {
                        // if next file -> GO !
                        if (_inputFiles.Count - 1 > i)
                        {
                            i++;
                        }
                        // if not -> END !
                        else
                        {
                            return RETURN_VALUE.CONVERTED;
                        }
                    }
                    // Error
                    if (_returnCode == (Int32)RETURN_CODE.ERROR_INPUT
                        || _returnCode == (Int32)RETURN_CODE.ERROR_OUTPUT
                        || _returnCode == (Int32)RETURN_CODE.ERROR_SCRIPT_NOT_FOUND
                        || _returnCode == (Int32)RETURN_CODE.ERROR_SCRIPT_ERROR)
                    {
                        File.WriteAllText(Path.ChangeExtension(_outputPath, "log"), "Error : this file has provocated an error while being converted, that's why he isn't converted. Ask an administrator and give him the code: " + _returnCode);
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        RETURN_CODE _code = (RETURN_CODE)_returnCode;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return RETURN_VALUE.INCORRECT;
                    }
                    // End and return
                }
            } // FIN BOUCLE AWAITER
        } // FIN BOUCLE FICHIERS
          // RETURN VALUE -> Conversion end !
        return RETURN_VALUE.ERROR;
    }
```

About the problem:

When I start my service, if it doesn't find any conversion to do, the UC used will stay around 0.06 % which is what I find as normal. When a conversion is needed, the service will start the conversion process which is an exe that will take 40% of my UC. When this process is present, my service process will take ~41,5%. When the conversion end, the service process get back to a very low uc level (almost the same 0.06%)

That's why I'm supposing that my conversion task does not "separate" as it should from the service process. The 2 process aren't linked when I look at them with the win 1à task manager.

Here are my thought about this, but don't know what to think:

1. The fact that I use Task.Factory.StartNew is a problem and I shouldn't have handle my threads like this.
2. It can't be an overload due to loops as I'm for the moment blocked with 1 licence, which mean that files are converted 1 by 1 and that I don't open a 2nd thread if I already have one, as I have only 1 licence.
3. The file reading part is badly coded
4. I start my program as debug configuration and not as a service as I am still testing it with VS2015. Maybe publishing it would make it lighter ?

But at the moment I don't find any answer to what can be the problem that create this use of UC by the service. I understand it for the conversion exe, but not for the service.

Comment: Tasks aren't threads, they don't need to be put in lists nor do they need multiple cancellation tokens. Calling `.Result` in a loop means you block until the task finishes. The resulting code is so complicated that it's very hard to understand what it does. Wouldn't a `Parallel.ForEach(whatever,it=>ConverterRunner(it,token))` have done the same?

Comment: The things is that I don't want to block the service. I just want that at another "Turn" of the service it look at the résult of the task.
I think that I'm misunderstanding task and thread yes.

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew` is completely discouraged unless you are tied to .NET 4.0 and cannot upgrade to 4.5. Prefer `Task.Run` always

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I saw something about that yes, I was on my way to try this. But could it be the problem ?

Comment: Not likely. If I understood you correctly, you can only run the converter once at a time. If this is the case, why are you using `Task` at all? Just run it synchronously

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto it can evolved later to more than one conversion simultaneously.

Comment: @GrégoryL `Parallel.ForEach` uses the current thread as well for processing. If you don't want it to block, put it inside `Task.Run`. If you want to spawn the tasks yourself, an `var results=await Task.WhenAll(whatever.Select(it=>Task.Run(()=>ConverterRunner(it,token))))` will spawn all tasks at once. Or a `var results=whatever.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(4).Select(it=>ConverterRunner(it,token));`

Comment: The problem with this is that conversion can appear later, as it's a website that generate them. I transform my factory in Task.Run as you saif but I still face the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the mistake, my bad, did it pretty wrong.

They weren't any problem with tasks, only with my work function that do a while(!end). I thought it wouldn't take this much UC.

I just add a thread.sleep(1000) before loping again as it's a detection system it's not a problem.